# Develop orchestration flow in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

i need develop an orchestration flow but i don't know for where start. I must use WSO2 and the requirements are the next:

Make 3 microservices;

Microservice 1.- Get the client data such as: Complete name, Address, Client Number.

Microservice 2.- Account number, Vigency, Bank.

Microservice 3.- Account balance, last 3 movements, date.

I must make petition that enter for the ESB and trought the EndPoint enters an flow and this flow going see the client data, then the account data and then the of the balance.

If the client is minor of 22 years age that indicate that no are ready for do the consulte.

Return this information to the initial query

I have a remote idea for how start. WSO2 offers a suite of tools such an Integration Studio IDE, Api Manager, Micro-Integrator, Enterprise Integrator, etc..

I believe that i must start developemnt a Flow of each microservice using Integration Studio and then do the orchestration using Enterprise Integrator???

Please guide me, i need orientation, I am scattered and confused, and really i dont know how start, only need a little biit of impulse for understand about of this matter, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/exposing-several-services-as-a-single-service/) tutorial. If you have specific questions you can ask questions here.

Comment: thanks for help to indicate me for where start, finally i can do my orchestration satisfactory way